# Doesn't parse.com cloud code accepts string.includes()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, parse-platform

I'm trying to do this in parse cloud code:

```
var userMail = userModel.get('email');
console.log((typeof userMail));
console.log(userMail);
if (userMail.includes("mydomain.com")){
    // do something with this string
}
```

The 2 console logs display the correct email address and `string` on the parse.com cloud code logs.

I'm trying to run the [includes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) function of a `String`. The code above works pretty well on `node`. However, on parse.com, I'm getting this error:

```
Result: TypeError: Object myemail@mydomain.com has no method 'includes'
at e.<anonymous> (main.js:1418:22)
at e.i (Parse.js:14:27703)
at e.a.value (Parse.js:14:27063)
at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:14:27774)
at e.i (Parse.js:14:27703)
at Parse.js:14:28316
at l (Parse.js:14:28120)
at e.a.value (Parse.js:14:28301)
at e.i (Parse.js:14:27748)
at e.a.value (Parse.js:14:27063)
```

Why doesn't this string have the `includes` method?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes` wasn't introduced until ECMAScript 6

the javascript engine being used must be older

but you could always use [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

```
if (userMail.indexOf("mydomain.com") > -1){
    // do something with this string
}
```

Comment: Interesting to know if it will be different in my own parse-server deployment to heroku.

Answer (score 1):

It's because parse.com doesn't offers ES6 or if you prefere JS 1.8 in fact it uses JS1.6.x 
So includes() doesn't exist on this executing plateforme.
But you can use polyfill as advised on MDN